# Missing JSX expression container around literal string: "submit" react/jsx-no-literals

Tags: reactjs, frontend, jsx, eslint, eslint-plugin-react

I have just added `eslint-plugin-react` to my react project, while I'm trying to add a button to my project like this:

```js
<button type="submit">submit</button>
```

eslint starts to blame the code style and throws the following error:

```sh
  Line 46:55:  Strings not allowed in JSX files: "submit"  react/jsx-no-literals
```

any idea on this? any ideas and suggestions would be appreciated :)

Comment: It probably wants you to write `{"submit"}` instead. "submit" would be a string literal in the jsx, but anything in the braces {} is javascript.

Comment: this is the output while I'm doing it as you said
```Line 47:11:  Curly braces are unnecessary here  react/jsx-curly-brace-presence```

Comment: It's referring to the other submit. <button>{"submit"}</button>. Btw I just googled "react/jsx-no-literals" and all the info about the lint rule came up with examples and everything.

Comment: @windowsill finally I have managed to solve it by reading the GitHub repository, by the way thank you relly much ;)